# Ajax form issue in lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with Ajax email form. My form is inside of a lightbox call. So whenever I submit the form instead of submitting the form it goes to the requested php file.

```js
$('.lightbox').nivoLightbox();



$('#contact-form').on('submit', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var success_msg = $(this).find('.success-msg'),
       error_msg = $(this).find('.error-msg'),
       data = $(this).serialize();

   if (validateEmail( $(this).find('input[name="email"]').val() )) {
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: $(this).attr('action'),
         data: data,
         success: function() {
            success_msg.fadeIn(1000);
            error_msg.fadeOut(500);
         }
      });
   } else {
      error_msg.fadeIn(1000);
      success_msg.fadeOut(500);
   }

return false;
});
```

```html
<p class="contact-help">Need any help?  <a href="#contact-form-popup" class="lightbox" data-lightbox-type="inline">Contact us now</a></p>


<!-- =========================
     CONTACT US  
============================== -->
<div class="contact-form-popup" id="contact-form-popup">
 <h2 class="heading-text text-center">Get in Touch</h2>
 <form action="php/sendmail.php" id="contact-form">
  <div class="">
   <table class="table table-bordered table-form">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td class="col-md-6">
       <label for="contact-name" class="text-uppercase">Enter Your Name</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact-name" name="name" placeholder="e.g. Jogn Doe">
      </td>
      <td class="col-md-6">
       <label for="contact-email" class="text-uppercase">Your Email</label>
       <input type="email" id="contact-email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g. email@example.com">
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
       <label for="contact-tel" class="text-uppercase">Your Number</label>
       <input type="tel" id="contact-tel" name="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g. 000 1234 55478">
      </td>
      <td>
       <label for="contact-sub" class="text-uppercase">Subject</label>
       <input type="text" id="contact-sub" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g. Help / Subject">
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
       <label for="contact-msg" class="text-uppercase">Your Name</label>
       <textarea name="message" id="contact-msg" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="4" placeholder="Type your message.."></textarea>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>

  <div class="text-center">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-base btn-lg"><span>Get in Touch</span></button>
  </div>

  <div class="result">
   <p class="success-msg"><img src="icons/check.svg" class="icon inject-svg icon-xs" alt=""> Thanks! Your message has been sent.</p>
   <p class="error-msg"><img src="icons/close-circle.svg" class="icon inject-svg icon-xs" alt=""> Sorry, Something went wrong!</p>
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

Here's my code. **#contact-form-popup** is hidden from css, and when I call **$('.lightbox').nivoLightbox();** it appears. But form submission do not work.

Comment: You stopped the form action by `e.preventDefault();` remove it !

Comment: Does not work whether I remove it or keep it !

Comment: Redirect to sendmail.php and says: Notice: Undefined index: name in E:/......sendmail.php on line 3

But it should not go to that page since it's an Ajax form .. FYI, I am loading from my localhost XAMPP

Comment: In the `sendmail.php` can you do `print_r($_POST)` and see what it prints ?

Comment: Or else after `data = $(this).serialize();` can do `console.log(data)` and see what is inside `data` ?

Comment: I did console.log(data) , It I get all my desired data in the console. But problem is somewhere else.. 

I think since the form is in a llightbox, contact form ajax call could not reach it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95079/discussion-between-sulthan-allaudeen-and-anwar-hussain).